# How to toggle between Isotope's layout modes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jquery-masonry

Two questions, everybody:

1) How do I toggle [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) on and off?

2) How do I toggle layout modes? That is, how do I go from this:

```
 $('.content').isotope({  itemSelector : '.hentry',
                          layoutMode : 'cellsByRow',
                          cellsByRow : { columnWidth : 240, rowHeight : 360 } });
```

to this:

```
 $('.content').isotope({  itemSelector : '.hentry',
                          layoutMode : 'masonry'});
```

with a simple click switch? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/dbgFa/

1) To disable Isotope after initializing it, use the [destroy method](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#destroy)

```
$('.content').isotope('destroy')
```

Then turn it back on by triggering Isotope again

```
$('.content').isotope( /* options */ )
```

2) You would change layout modes just like your example code, by setting the layoutMode in the options. This will also trigger a re-layout and the layout will change.